# Java Certificate-based Mutual Authentication over HTTPS

Tags: java, authentication, ssl, https, certificate

i'am new with HTTP/SSL (HTTPS) authentication, i have to do a mutual authentication over https with Java , i read this article https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19226-01/820-7627/bncbs/index.html to understand the basic of HTTPS Client Authentication , i do a example in php -cURL something like this:

```
curl --cert ./client.101.cer --key ./client.key --cacert ./ca.cer https://***.******.com.ar/x.php
```

that returns `["SUCCESS",[]].`

I have to do the same in java but i don't know which is the correct way to do? using something similar like cURL but in java?

Comment: I'am using Java SE 6  (jdk6.0_32)